# How to add custom date format in magento backend?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am trying to add custom date format in Magento from backend, but there is no way to add custom Date format. Please check screenshot shown below

[image]

The format I want is `l - m/d/Y`(Wednesday - 03/04/2015)